# Creating a counter in a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, counter

I have made a Rock Paper Scissors game in a Java GUI. It's very simple and now the only last piece of it I need help with is creating a counter or scoreboard within my GUI. I know that there is some other links on SO but none of them seem to be able to help me with my specific problem.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class rpsGUItest extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public rpsGUItest(){
    super("Rock, Paper, Scissors");


    //settings of the GUI
    setSize(600, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    //Creating the panels
    JPanel head = new JPanel();
    JPanel body = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel footer = new JPanel();


    //Creating the Buttons
    JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");
    JButton paper = new JButton("Paper");
    JButton scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");

    //Button Functions
    rock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double picker = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            if(picker == 0.0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Rock, the Computer picked Rock, it's a tie!");


            }
            else if(picker == 1.0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Rock, the Computer picked Paper, the Computer Wins!, for some reason.");


            }
            else if(picker == 2.0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Rock, the Computer picked Scissors, You win! ");

            } 
        }
    });
    paper.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double picker = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            if(picker == 0.0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Paper, the Computer picked Rock, You win!");


            }
            else if(picker == 1.0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Paper, the Computer picked Paper, it's a tie!");


            }
            else if(picker == 2.0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Paper, the Computer picked Scissors, the Computer wins! ");
            }



        }
    });
    scissors.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double picker = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            if(picker == 0.0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Scissors, the Computer picked Rock, the Computer wins!");


            }
            else if(picker == 1.0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Scissors, the Computer picked Paper, You win!");


            }
            else if(picker == 2.0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Scissors, the Computer picked Scissors, it's a tie!");
            }


        }
    });
    //Head Panel
    JLabel title = new JLabel("ROCK PAPER SCISSORS");
    head.add(title);

    //Creating the Check Boxes


    //add the Check Boxes to Panel 2


    //Creating the label and text area


    //GridBag Spacing Stuff
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(15,15,15,15);



    //Adding things to the body
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    body.add(label);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    body.add(rock, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    body.add(paper, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    body.add(scissors, gbc);
    //positioning the panel's 
    add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(head, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

I know this is a lot of code but I wasn't sure which parts would be needed. Sorry! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: ...or rather the "specific" problem.

Comment: I don't know how to create a counter in Java to keep track of the score of the computer or user winning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't able to access fields declared in the rspGUItest class from within the actionPerformed method because actionPerformed is in the ActionListener interface, not rpsGUItest. One solution would be to declare your counters as public static fields and access them statically from the callback method.

In rpsGUItest:

```
public static int computerWins = 0;
public static int userWins = 0;

public rpsGUItest(){
    super("Rock, Paper, Scissors");
```

And in the ActionListener:

```
else if(picker == 1.0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Rock, the Computer picked Paper, the Computer Wins!, for some reason.");

            rpsGUItest.computerWins += 1;
        }
```

Comment: It's telling me that is an "Illegal modifier for parameter, only final is permitted."

Comment: Oops, my bad. You should declare computerWins and userWins in the class outside of the constructer, i.e. right after the line private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Comment: Ahh alright. Sweet! Thank you! I can do it from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code that you put up is missing a closing bracket for the class. To make a counter you can just make a private global variable

```
public rpsGUItest(){
    super("Rock, Paper, Scissors");
    int computerWins = 0;
    int userWins = 0;
```

and in the corresponding area if the user wins put

```
else if(picker == 1.0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked Rock, the Computer picked Paper, the Computer Wins!, for some reason.");

            computerWins += 1;
        }
```

Then you can display it in a JLabel

Comment: It's saying that is an "illegal modifier for parameter computerWins, only final is permitted."